# Change background of Canvas in Fabric JS

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to change the background of Canvas. I am able to change the background of canvas but once i click on the background . It reload the original background and does not show the changed background. Hope you understand what i am trying to say. Following is the code which implementing to change the background.Based on select box,image will load

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="canvas-container" style="float:left;">
        <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc">     </canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<select id="color" class="styled-select">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setBackgroundImage("red.png", canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
$('select#color').on('change', function() {
    var imageName=this.value+".png"
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(imageName, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
})
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your problem so that it will be better understood!!

Comment: How about removing second `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');`?

Comment: Oh! my bad , i was creating the new canvas object every time that why it was happening.. Thank you for pointing me in right direction @sapics . Actually i am magento developer and implementing something with fabric and magento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Stack overflow!

You have two times `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');`. Remove last.

To change background color you only need `canvas.backgroundColor` property:

```
$('select#color').on('change', function() {
    canvas.backgroundColor = this.value;
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

I have created a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/q6Y6k/15/

I hope this helps.